# is this a mysql bug about update check?

Tags: mysql, sql

we have databases `db1` and `db2`, each of them has a table `t` with a column `a`

```sql
create database db1;
create database db2;

create table t(a int);
insert into t values (1);
```

then we `use db1` and run the SQLs:

```sql
mysql> update db2.t, (select 1 as a) as t set db2.t.a=1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> update (select 1 as a) as t, db2.t set db2.t.a=1;
ERROR 1288 (HY000): The target table t of the UPDATE is not updatable
```

As you can see, the first SQL runs successfully, and the second report an error.

Why does this happen? is this a MySQL bug?

I am using MySQL version:

```sql
mysql> select version();
+-------------------------+
| version()               |
+-------------------------+
| 8.0.22-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Both tables have the same short alias `t`. Alter, remove ambiguity. `UPDATE (SELECT 1 AS a) AS t1, db2.t AS t2 SET t2.a=1;`

Comment: sure looks like a bug to me.  FWIW doesn't happen for me on mariadb 10.5; what version are you on?

Comment: @Akina but db2.t is *not* the alias; there is no ambiguity here.  and if there was ambiguity, it should give an error (as indeed it does if you `set t.a=1`)

Comment: The name of the table is an alias of this table until it is set explicitly.

Comment: @Akina I don't understand what you are saying

Comment: @ysth I do not see any other explanation. Maybe this is a bug that the table alias is looked up without its databas specification. I always use a rule "if more than one table is used then each table must have explicit and unique alias", and no problems similar to described one.

Comment: @ysth I am using MySQL8.0

Comment: the only explanation to me is that, in a multiple table update statement, mysql processes the list of tables from left to right, and  it stops right away and trigger ERROR 1288 if the very first table is not UPDATABLE. But if the first table is valid, it continues to processe the statement, even if next tables are not updatable. I wouldn't qualify this as a bug.  There's absolutely no blocking issue with that, and its logical to me that if you want to update only one table, you declare it first. However I re-read carefully the doc on UPDATE statement and couldn't find this behaviour explained.

Comment: @ThomasG for this explanation, the sql `update t1, (select 1 as a) as t, db2.t set db2.t.a=1;` shall work, but it raises the same error

Comment: And what is t1 in that case???

Comment: @ThomasG just a common table `create table t1(a int)`